# How to replace underscore(_) with space (' ') in angular view?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm displaying array keys in header of a table and I have underscore in my keys. I want to replace underscore with space in html table. I do not want to do it in component as I have other requirements.

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th *ngFor="let header of printFields">{{header}}</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let ab of printData">
           <td *ngIf="ab.Bill_Number">{{ab.Bill_Number}}</td>
           <td>.....</td>
           <td>.....</td>
       </tr>     
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If there is only one instance you can use this,

```
 {{ header.replace('_', ' ') }}
```

or else you have to use filter

```
App.filter('strReplace', function () {
 return function (input, from, to) {
 input = input || '';
 from = from || '';
 to = to || '';
 return input.replace(new RegExp(from, 'g'), to);
 };
});
```

and use it like

```
 {{ header | strReplace:'_':' ' }}
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: Where to add the second one? It seems like Angular JS code. I'm using Angular2

Comment: you can add the code to your script file, the file in which you have declared your app

Answer (score 17):

You can use a pipe

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'replaceUnderscore'})
export class ReplaceUnderscorePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value? value.replace(/_/g, " ") : value;
  }
}
```

Then use it like

```
{{ header|replaceUnderscore}}
```

You could also make a more generic version that takes the pattern to replace and the replacement as parameters, like @Ash-b's answer for angularJs

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'replace'})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, strToReplace: string, replacementStr: string): string {

    if(!value || ! strToReplace || ! replacementStr)
    {
      return value;
    }

 return value.replace(new RegExp(strToReplace, 'g'), replacementStr);
  }
}
```

And use it like

```
{{ header| replace : '_' : ' ' }}
```

Here is a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u3g5tu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Also learned pipes with your solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following :

1. create a pipe
2. in the transform method write the following

   ```
   transform(value: any, args?: any): string {
       let [first, ...rest] = value.split("_");
       if (rest.length === 0) return first;
       else return `${first} ${rest.join(" ")}`;
   }
   ```

   this code will handle if the key have underscore or not.

   - key = angular_7  =>   angular 7
   - key = angular   =>   angular

Answer (score 1):

this case angular 6:

```
 underscore(selectkpi){
    this.selectedUnderKpi = selectkpi.replace(' ', '_');
    var a = this.selectedUnderKpi.
    console.log("ini = ",a);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use regex for that-

```
header.replace(/_/g, " "); // if you need space
header.replace(/_/g, ""); //if you don't need space
```

Comment: what is the type of header? is this string type?

Comment: Ok you can create a method and pass header to that function and inside function you can write above code..